# jQuery Drag & Drop into a Text Area

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Using jQuery, and looking to let user drag a placeholder into a text area.

Each placeholder is a `<span>` which has a `class='placeholder'`. The text area `id` is simply `'main_text'`.

So, user should be able to drag each placeholder `span` on top of text area, drop it, and then text gets inserted.

Most desirable effect would be to insert text where they drop the placeholder, but I have pretty much given up on that one. At this point, just to get it working so it inserts the text anywhere at all would be a good start.

Has anyone successfully done this? Thanks -

Comment: Did you find a solution to drop the placeholder where they drop? I need this too...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you can use the textarea directly as droppable thus I made a little hack which on drag-start positions a div directly over the textarea. The div is the actual droppable which then inserts the text of the draggable into the textarea

Check here for a demo

http://jsbin.com/egefi (http://jsbin.com/egefi/edit for the code)

It inserts at current textcaret position I don't think inserting at current mouse cursor position is even possible.

```
function insertAtCaret(area, text) {
    //... adapted from http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/425/how-to-insert-text-into-a-textarea-where-the-cursor-is/
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        accept: "span.placeholder",       
        drop: function(ev, ui) {
            insertAtCaret($("textarea#main_text").get(0), ui.draggable.eq(0).text());
        }
    };

    $("span.placeholder").draggable({
        helper:'clone',
        start: function(event, ui) {
            var txta = $("textarea#main_text");
            $("div#pseudodroppable").css({
                position:"absolute",
                top:txta.position().top,
                left:txta.position().left,
                width:txta.width(),
                height:txta.height()
            }).droppable(options).show();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $("div#pseudodroppable").droppable('destroy').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, it certainly seems to work. I still think that without the placeholder dropping onto exact spot, it's unusable in a real-world-app, so I will have to decide if I want to use it or not in my app, but, as I said - answers the question. Thanks -